# How do I avoid empty sections when removing a setting from .git/config ?

Tags: git, configuration-files

If I do `git config foo.bar baz`, this adds a `foo` section to `.git/config`:

```
...
[foo]
        bar = baz
...
```

I can remove the setting again with `git config --unset foo.bar`, but the section remains in the file, with nothing in it:

```
...
[foo]
...
```

If I add another `foo` setting with `git config foo.bar baz`, `git-config` doesn't add it to the empty `foo` section; it starts a new one:

```
...
[foo]
[foo]
        bar = baz
...
```

My questions are:

1. Is this expected behavior?
2. If not, is it a bug?
3. Is there a way to avoid a possible proliferation of empty sections in the config file when unsetting configuration?

Comment: This should be fixed with Git 2.18 (Q2 2018). See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50274206/6309).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I avoid empty sections when removing a setting from .git/config ?

That should be fixed with Gti 2.18 (Q2 2018):
"`git config --unset a.b`", when "`a.b`" is the last variable in an otherwise empty section "`a`", left an empty section "a" behind, and worse yet, a subsequent "`git config a.c value`" did not reuse that
empty shell and instead created a new one.
These have been (partially) corrected.

See [commit c71d8bb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c71d8bb38a73abc910a63bf7a81f3869dc9c2f34), [commit 22aedfc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/22aedfccd0cfe7c8f09a990cf4777efc7f27bd2e), [commit 6ae996f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6ae996f2acf3ad780b8d338c81e24143f0b0d304), [commit 5221c31](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5221c3159f670281ff36b6adbdf568661e930b50), [commit 668b9ad](https://github.com/git/git/commit/668b9ade6bcafbed1577468902d27c05c17cf026), [commit fee8572](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fee8572c6ddf6afcfeba023067fea36b835a9df4), [commit 8032cc4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8032cc4462b8af268fe457c2a0431473334dfd18), [commit b73bdc3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b73bdc34c06358359750a896983a2ea85b694ca0), [commit 422e8ef](https://github.com/git/git/commit/422e8ef26d35a7e54d5b7b990669f4a525cb8828) (09 Apr 2018), and [commit dde154b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dde154b5bd84e6258b496498901eb24b4914ec6b), [commit 85bf5d6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/85bf5d61e717f79f7ac68d15e336e54293035405), [commit 46fc89c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/46fc89ce74b46e88764c796b3ab20d5ab90a5e96), [commit e931395](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e9313952bf85bcc8b602f582b2e71660d670f97b), [commit efbaca1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/efbaca1b69b2d08429889259489b73c8eea16a1d), [commit 83b7fd8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/83b7fd87714c4b70553c56987756ff319ccc7ec6) (03 Apr 2018) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4f4d0b4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4f4d0b42bae8091fd989aa6d7db72ecdd86aa36b), 08 May 2018)</sup>

> ### git config --unset: remove empty sections (in the common case)
>
> The original reasoning for not removing section headers upon removal of
>   the last entry went like this: the user could have added comments about
>   the section, or about the entries therein, and if there were other
>   comments there, we would not know whether we should remove them.
>
> In particular, a concocted example was presented that looked like this
>   (and was added to t1300):

```
# some generic comment on the configuration file itself
# a comment specific to this "section" section.
[section]
# some intervening lines
# that should also be dropped

key = value
# please be careful when you update the above variable
```

> The ideal thing for `git config --unset section.key` in this case would
>   be to leave only the first line behind, because all the other comments
>   are now obsolete.
>
> However, this is unfeasible, short of adding a complete Natural Language
>   Processing module to Git, which seems not only a lot of work, but a
>   totally unreasonable feature (for little benefit to most users).
>
> Now, the real kicker about this problem is: most users do not edit their
>   config files at all! In their use case, the config looks like this
>   instead:

```
[section]
    key = value
```

> ... and it is totally obvious what should happen if the entry is removed: the entire section should vanish.

Answer (score 4):

To answer point 3, you can use the result from `git config --get-regexp` to decide when to cleanup:

```
git config --unset "foo.bar";
# Cleanup empty "foo" section.
# Regular expression has a trailing period to avoid testing against
# other sections that share the same prefix (e.g. "foo" vs "food").
if ! git config --get-regexp '^foo\.'; then
    git config --remove-section "foo" 2> /dev/null;
fi;
```

Answer (score 3):

There is `git config --remove-section` so you could delete whole section. But yes, for me it looks like a bug that it creates a new section if an empty exists.

Answer (score 1):

Thomas Rast brought to my attention [this thread on the git developer mailing list](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/219505/focus=219513).

According to my understanding of Peff's description there, the problem would be easy to fix if the programming of the config parser were not so ad-hoc.  After the file is parsed, the result is a structure that contains the configuration settings, but none of the original structure of the file.  Since the information about section structure is not available to callers, the setting-inserting code can't know whether there is an empty section with the right title. Also removing empty sections is a little bit tricky because they might contain important comments, which should *not* be automatically removed just because the last functional part of the section is removed.

The conclusion was that:

1. No, it is not expected behavior;
2. Yes, it is a bug.

This sort of programming is tedious but straightforward, so I'll see if I can work up a patch.

Comment: I did not do a patch.